# Using loop in fsolve and plugging the result to a function

Tags: matlab

I have functions which has totally 4 unknowns (2x2).
I got the solution. But what I am going to do is to vary some parameters so that I can see how the original solution changes.

But matlab keeps saying that in A(I)=B, 'I' and the number of element B must be the same.

Example code could be such as( in the code, psi01 psi02 psi03 psi04 are the varying parameters);

```
R=902;
psi01=0.9:-0.1:0.1;
psi11=0.9:-0.1:0.1;
psi02=0.1:0.1:0.9;
psi12=0.1:0.1:0.9;
E0=[R/4 R/4; R/4 R/4];
for i=1:9
vv=@(E) [
g/E(2,1)-(th1+psi12(i)/psi11(i)*th2)-((psi01(i)/psi11(i))+a*b)/b*(g/E(1,1)-(rho*b*    (psi11(i)/psi01(i))/(psi01(i)/psi11(i)+a*b))*(th1+psi12(i)/psi11(i)*th2)*(th1+psi02(i)    /psi11(i)*th2)  );
g/E(2,2)-(psi11(i)/psi12(i)*th1+th2)-((psi02(i)/psi12(i))+a*b)/b*(g/E(1,2)-(rho*b*(psi12(i)/psi02(i))/(psi02(i)/psi12(i)+a*b))*(psi11(i)/psi12(i)*th1+th2)*(psi01(i)/psi02(i)*th1+th2)  );
    R-(E(1,1)+E(1,2)+E(1,1)+E(2,2));
    E(1,2)- c(E)*E(1,1);
    E(2,2)- d(E)*E(2,1)
    ];
Ep2(i)=fsolve(vv, E0);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If the result of fsolve is a 2x2 array, then how can you expect to save it as a scalar?

```
Ep2(i)=fsolve(vv, E0);
```

Ep2 is being used here to store a single element, a scalar. You can't stuff 4 elements into one, and not get an error.

Use a 3-dimensional array, a struct, or use a cell array.